# Google PHP AppEngine - Deployment Issue with PHP file not being uploaded

Tags: deployment, google-cloud-platform

I have a very simple PHP app that allows a User to enter names of Cities or Zip-codes into a search box, and the User gets auto-complete suggestions based on data stored in my Google CloudSQL server.

- index.html - Renders a simple search box where users can enter search keys and they get auto-complete suggestions. Accomplished via Twitter's typeahead.js library (jQuery plugin).
- city.php - PHP file that acts as a translation layer. Receives request from the browser and initiates connection to my Google CloudSQL server where I have a simple database with some city and zipcode data. Returns the data back to the browser as an array.

This works on my local Mac OS X Apache server. I am trying to get this setup to work on Google PHP AppEngine. I created an app.yaml file that looks like this:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 2
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
static_files: index.html
upload: index.html

- url: /(.*)
static_files: www/\1
upload: (.*)

- url: /(.+\.php)$
script: \1
```

This is where I run into an issue. When I run gcloud app deploy from my local folder (which houses index.html, city.php, and app.yaml), I get the following message in the logs.

```
Some files were skipped. Pass `--verbosity=info` to see which ones.
You may also view the gcloud log file, found at
[/Users/arjunshah/.config/gcloud/logs/2016.11.13/12.31.04.137587.log].
```

When I run gcloud app deploy with log verbosity, I see the following:

```
INFO: Could not find any remote repositories associated with     [/Users/arjunshah/Documents/autocomplete]. Cloud diagnostic tools may not be able to display the correct source code for this deployment.
File upload done.
INFO: Manifest: [{'app.yaml': {'sourceUrl':      'https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.ashah-146101.appspot.com/abbe3c7fc03eb43497686990488c54e2ae0533ea', 'sha1Sum': 'abbe3c7fc03eb43497686990488c54e2ae0533ea'}, 'index.html': {'sourceUrl': 'https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.ashah-146101.appspot.com/1865620cc55de1902c2a9636df601f532cb2657a', 'sha1Sum': '1865620cc55de1902c2a9636df601f532cb2657a'}, 'city.php': {'sourceUrl': 'https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.ashah-146101.appspot.com/64999cc8da06416a54be99c43e6e017aa0c1d01a', 'sha1Sum': '64999cc8da06416a54be99c43e6e017aa0c1d01a'}}]
Updating service [default]...
INFO: Previous default version [ashah-146101/default/20161113t122802] is an automatically scaled standard environment app, so not stopping it.
```

The index.html page loads fine, but when I try to enter names of cities (that I know are in the database), I see the following error in the Google Browser Inspect Element console.

```
Failed to load resource: https://ashah-146101.appspot.com/city.php?query=P the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

Please help!

Comment: This is an unlikely solution, but worth trying: could you change the order of the request-path handlers in the app.yaml file? It seems the line `url: /(.*)` is making it impossible for requests to reach the lower line, `url /(.+\.php)$`. This might be why the deployment skips those files, but this is just a hypothesis.

Comment: [Another thread](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=1168) where users saw this error message recommends a workaround that I can't be certain is related, but could also work, so try this afterwards: run `gcloud config set app/num_file_upload_processes 1`.

Comment: It's unclear what's going on, and if you're inactive on this question, no future user will be able to determine what happened here. Is this still happening for you? Have you looked into my latest comments?